# How to run c# code using notepad++?

Tags: c#, cmd, notepad++

I have trouble executing code that I have written in notepad++. As from what I have researched online, I should edit path in system variable to this C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319. I have already changed it and it's still not working. After I type in test.cs, a windows form will pop up stating that windows can't open this file. Here is an image of my command line:

[image: CMD Picture]

Here is also the small code that I have written:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("***");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [.NET Tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/hello-world)

Comment: This isn't about compiling C# code. The compilation succeeded. This is about running the result. And you're not trying to do that using Notepad++ (nor should you). So out of "How to compile c# code using notepad++?", only the "How to" is relevant to this question.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Or is this just an academic appraoch?

Comment: I guess you need to just enter `test.exe`. `test.cs` is your source file and `test.exe` is the executable file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm just trying things out using cmd.

Comment: Honestly, why are you writing code in Notepad++ when you can get [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/) for free?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After compiling your c# file, execute it by just typing the name in your command prompt. Don't use the extension again. Just type

```
test
```

after compiling successfully in your cmd prompt, and you'll be fine. You can also use

```
test.exe
```

to run it instead of just test.

Comment: Your and mine responses are same except formatting difference. You get 3 votes and also marked as answer and I get only one vote. I envy you :)

Comment: Thumbs up! Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

As I can see from the image, don't type test.cs. Instead type test and it will execute. test.cs is a c# prograram file and it can be opened in visual studio or notepad or can be compiled but can't be executed. It can be executed only after compilation. Compilation will give test.exe as an output and to run test.exe you can mention either test.exe or just test.